# Change of integral limits

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I came across above equation. There is a variable change in this integral. But when I do that I found:
\begin{equation}
t = \tau - t_0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
W_R(t_0,t_1) = \int_0^{t_1-t_0} e^{A(t_1-t-t_0)t}BB'e^{A'(t_1-t-t_0)t}dt
\end{equation}

What am I missing in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution is $t=t_1-\tau$. Do that and you should get the correct integral. Indeed

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}e^{A(t_1-\tau)}BB'e^{A'(t_1-\tau)}~\mathrm{d}\tau=-\int_{t_1-t_0}^{0}e^{At}BB'e^{A't}~\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{t_1-t_0}e^{At}BB'e^{A't}~\mathrm{d}t.$$